# Can't create credit card token with stripe (django)

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, stripe-payments

I'm using django for a web app and I'm trying to process payments with stripe, I'm having trouble creating a token (I think that's a problem). Here's my html/javascript code for the checkout page

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="{% url 'checkout:p' %}" id="payment-form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        number:<input class="card-number" type='text'>
        cvc:<input class="card-cvc" type='text'>
        month:<input class="card-expiry-month" type='text'>
        year:<input class="card-expiry-year" type='text'>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('form').submit((fucnction(){
                var $form = $('#payment-form');
                Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_KaWOobBc2ELxFoSoqmS1gtz2');

                Stripe.card.createToken({
                    number: $('.card-number').val(),
                    cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
                    exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
                    exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
                        }, stripeResponseHandler);

                function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {


                 if (response.error) {
                    // Show the errors on the form
                    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
                  } else {
                    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
                        var token = response.id;
                    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                     $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
                    // and submit
                    $form.get(0).submit();
                  }
                }
            });
        </script>
        <input type="text" name="life" value=42>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
```

Then here's the view I'm using.

```
class CheckoutView(View):
    template_name = "checkout/checkout.html"
    credit_card_form = CreditCardInfo
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        stripe.api_key = "sk_test_bb2N1MRHoMGhvnc4ZCvrMRMk"
        life = request.POST.get('life', '') 
        card = request.POST.get('stripeToken', '')

        stripe.Charge.create(
            amount= 10.00,
            currency="USD",
            card=card,
            desciription="Test charge")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

The error message that I get is "You have passed a blank string for 'card'. You should remove the 'card' parameter from your request or supply a non-blank value." I'm assuming this just means that I'm not properly creating the credit card token, but I could be wrong. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Could you put `console.log(token);` right after `var token = response.id;` line and see what is the value printed on the console? Thanks.

Comment: I added and changed $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val('42')); for both the if and the else statement to see if the value was being sent through the post request, and I did if card == 42: (redirect to home page), and it didn't redirect mean that the value isn't being sent through the post request. Also I tried console.log(token), but it refreshes the page when I click submit to I can't see the token.

Comment: Thanks, but then comment out `$form.get(0).submit();` temporarily and leave `console.log(token)` call there. What is printed?

Answer (score 0):

The `card` parameter shouldn't be a `stripeToken`, it should be something like this

```
"card": {
    "id": "card_15EGuS2eZvKYlo2CgNp97XYZ",
    "object": "card",
    "last4": "4242",
    "brand": "Visa",
    "funding": "credit",
    "exp_month": 1,
    "exp_year": 2050,
    "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
    "country": "US",
    "name": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_city": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "customer": null
  },
```

You can checkout the rest of the paramters in [the stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

You should be passing `card={'id': stripeToken}` in your view.